# Deploy NodeJS server to AWS CodeDeploy ApplicationStart timeout

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

Im deploying a Nodejs server using a `appspec.yml` file with the following content

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /home/ubuntu/SimpleNodeJSServer
    overwrite: true
file_exists_behavior: OVERWRITE
hooks:
  AfterInstall:
    - location: deployment-scripts/install_dependencies.sh
      timeout: 1000
      runas: root
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: deployment-scripts/start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

The `AfterInstall` runs well and also the `ApplicationStart`.
The problem is the command in `ApplicationStart` never exits the script and get eventually a timeout.

```
cd /home/ubuntu/SimpleNodeJSServer
npm run ci-build
npm run start
exit 0
```

I have tried both with and without the `exit 0` but both get timeout.
It makes sense as the npm start (`node ./dist/src/index.js` which run app.listen()) is blocked by the running server as I understand.
But how can I make the script be over? I think im missing something basic here.
Thank you for the help

Comment: Can you share the `start` command of the package.json?

Comment: @AllanChua It’s in the question - node dist/src/index.js where index.js is the compiled ts of the entry point to express app

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nohup` to run the app on the background:

```bash
nohup npm run start &
```

Alternatively, you can try to use this to silence the logs

```bash
nohup npm start 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null&
```

You can also change the definition of the start script inside the `package.json` file.

```bash
nohup node ./dist/src/index.js &
```

Comment: It seems like a good solution but then i won't be able to see the logs on my servers terminal.

Comment: @ConiWright, it ls possible to redirect the logs to a file!

Comment: Thats very strange. The ApplicationStart still runs forever even tho ive added nohup to the command.